# Como inserir valores padrões na tabela junto com um valor variável?

Tags: mysql, query, autocompletar

Cenário:

Possuo um banco com 2 tabelas, a tabela A possui as telas de um app, e a tela B registra a atividade em cada tela, ficando deste modo:

```
   ____________________
  | Tabela A          |
   -------------------
  | id | tela         |
  | 0  | principal    |
  | 1  | menu         |
  | 2  | visualização |
   -------------------

   ___________________________
  | Tabela B          |       |
   ---------------------------
  | id | acoes        | tela  |
  | 0  | acao_1       |  0    |
  | 1  | acao_2       |  2    |
  | 2  | acao_3       |  1    |
   ---------------------------
```

Conforme vou adicionando ações na tabela B, e ja tendo uma tabela de referencia de telas, tabela A, gostaria de saber se o campo de tela, pudesse ser auto preenchido conforme a ação é inserida na tabela B.

Comment: Talvez um trigger pudesse te ajudar

Comment: Creio que eu não tenha compreendido. Você já tem uma tabela para armazenar ação e tela, ai quer adicionar uma ação de acordo com a tela que esta na tabela A certo? Basicamente no insert na tabela B você especifica a tela. Não tem outra forma de fazer isso com muitos pra muitos